# How to append or attach a pivot relationship to a model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, backend

I am trying to get the practice area record of lawyers from practice_areas table along side each time I get a lawyer's record from lawyer_profiles_table. This two tables (practice_areas and lawyer_profiles) are related with a pivot table named (lawyer_practice_area)

This code below are from the LawyerProfile Model

```
public function practice_areas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PracticeArea::class, "lawyer_practice_area", "practice_area_id", "lawyer_id");
    }
```

I tried getting it through an attribute by doing the below

```
public function getPracticeAreasAttribute()
{
    return $this->practice_areas();
}
```

and then appended it this way

```
protected $appends = ["practice_areas"];
```

but I keep getting this result on postman - "withtimestamps":"false"

See output below:-

```
 "id": 1,
        "city": "Hintztown",
        "state": "Iowa",
        "longitude": "-163.884102",
        "latitude": "-18.127927",
        "lawyer_profile": {
            "id": 26,
            "email": "serena.barrows@yahoo.com",
            "name": "Raoul Hegmann",
            "primary_location_id": 1,
            "photo_id": 39,
            "phone_number": "887.299.6204 x456",
            "about_lawyer": "Distinctio eos omnis autem error.",
            "practice_areas": {
                "withTimestamps": false
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be return $this->practice_areas; without the brackets?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want to use is [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Take a look at the documentation.

```php
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();

foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, eager loading just worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I didn't have to do all I was doing before by getting attribute and appending. I achieved what I wanted by using eager loading nested relationship this way,